# How to customize bash to add a system “bell” to all command-line questions (readlines)?

Tags: macos, bash

How can I customize bash to add a system “bell” whenever a readline (prompt user for input) is requested?

Running (upgraded) bash 4.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `\[\a\]` to `PS1` (normal prompt) and `PS2` (continuing prompt), e.g.

```
PS1="\u@\h\[\a\] "
```

will make the normal prompt

```
username@hostname
```

including a bell.

`\a` is the `BELL` character, `\[` and `\]` tell the shell it's not printed (for width calculation).

---

Add the `PS1=...` line to `~/.bash_profile` once you're happy with it.

---

This doesn't work for command-line based applications though. I don't think it's possible, since you can enter quite often input even while output is being printed; this accumulates. And a prompt just means nothing's currently writing to the terminal.

Comment: Yeah, I don’t want a bell on my PS1 prompt.  Basically, I’d like a bell if something is waiting for `readline` input.

Comment: But close enough, I suppose.  Maybe if I add this to one of the other PS# variables.  I’ll have to check.  (Anyway, thanks! ☺)

Comment: @Zearin I also found out since, that there is `PS3` used for actual prompts in `bash` scripts.